# Best Way to pass parameters from UI to backend

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, angularjs

What is the best way to send password from front end to back end when using the Rest based Web Services ?Is sending the password in encrypted form from Ui is enough to make the process secure?
Is it correct to pass parameters in request headers? If not what is the best approach?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to secure AngularJS $http.post data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25948230/how-to-secure-angularjs-http-post-data)

Comment: no doubts with `post`? send specific headers like auth tokens to validate user/transaction.

Comment: use http method POST, encrypt password by any javascript encrypt method, If you making API for mobile then use IMEI no of that mobile, use database session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no point encrypting a password from the UI, someone that would want to attack it can get your javascript source easily to get they key. If you use a hash, he can just send the same hash to the server.

Just put the password as is over an HTTPS connection and stay over SSL if you have a cookie with a session.

For the rest i'll link what herrh as linked in his comment : 
[Best Way to pass parameters from UI to backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35223745/best-way-to-pass-parameters-from-ui-to-backend)

Then answer of Endless is just the best you can have and this is what is done in the SE sites.

Answer (score 0):

If its a global application, I would say go ahead and pass user id and maintain a authorization layer to access any of the controller.
and if its a application for certain company or domain, try using ADFS for authentication and authorization.